# Name spelling is different in passport and educational documents

Tags: visas, usa, uk, paperwork, china

My name in my passport, Ielts certificate is Zakiya Khan Hakim Khan, whereas in all educational documents it is Zakia Hakeem Khan. kindly guide me what should I do in this case?  will they refuse me student visa?

Comment: Why do all educational documents use Zakia Hakeem Khan? Just curious

Comment: What is your nationality, and what country's visa are you applying for?

Comment: If your own language is written in a non-Latin script, are Hakim and Hakeem alternative spelling approximations of your name? Similarly with Zakia and Zakiya. It looks like the same name to me (given that many non-native English speakers have difficulty with the short 'i' sound that we use). Some of my own documents show three names, others only two.

Answer (score 1):

The variations of your names are within the reasonable range for transcriptions of documents and as such should be acceptable for visa officials.
If you have originals in your own language/script or other documents that show your name in a different script from English and this version also shows up in education papers and passport bring those, just to support your case.